# Every time I get the snapshot and then add a new "item" to the firebase database i only get back one item instead of all three

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: I only get back "CourseName instead of all the others"]

[image: Structure of my Firebase Database]

So I start the app in the simulator then the snapshot goes off inside viewdidappear then everything as expected is shown in the consolole...but after the @IBActionwhich ads a item(->CourseName, AddDate, AmountOfHoles) to firebase i only get CourseName in the console(AddedDate and AmonutOfHole is nil) but in the firebase console everything shows up...?
I would like to now how i can get the data(AddedDate,CourseName...)from the snapshot without error and add it to my tableview...?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class CoursesViewController: UITableViewController {

var ref = FIRDatabaseReference.init()


override func viewDidLoad() {

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

}

//TODO prevent crash when nil



override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    var CourseRef = ref.child("Course")

    //Get Snapshot from Course containing all children
    var refhandlr = CourseRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in


        let CourseName = snapshot.value!["CourseName"] as! String
        let AmonutOfHoles = snapshot.value!["AmountOfHoles"] as! String
        let AddedDate = snapshot.value!["AddedDate"] as! String

        print(snapshot.value)


        }, withCancelBlock: { error in

    })

}




@IBAction func addButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {


    // Alert View for input

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Course Item",message: "Add Course",preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

        //Get Date String
        let date = NSDate()
        print(date)

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
        print(dateString)

        let courseField = alert.textFields![0]
        let holesField = alert.textFields![1]

        let Course = self.ref.child("Course").childByAutoId()
        let amountOfHolesRef = Course.child("AmountOfHoles")
        let courseNameRef = Course.child("CourseName")
        let dateRef = Course.child("AddedDate")

        courseNameRef.setValue(courseField.text)
        amountOfHolesRef.setValue(holesField.text)
        dateRef.setValue(dateString)

    }

    //Cancel
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    }

    //TextField placeholder in alert
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (courseField: UITextField!) -> Void in

        courseField.placeholder = "Course Name"
    }
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (holesField: UITextField!) -> Void in

        holesField.placeholder = "Holes (6/9/18)"
    }

    //Add alert
    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are retrieving data every time a new child appears on `/Course/` (`CourseRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded`), when calling the first `.setValue(courseField.text)` your code is triggering the event listener and logging the entry with only the `CourseName`.

So make sure that when adding a new `Course` you call `setValue()` one time only.

Your code will look like this:

```
    let Course = self.ref.child("Course").childByAutoId()

    let course = ["AddedDate": dateString,
        "CourseName": courseField.text,
        "AmountOfHoles": holesField.text]

    Course.setValue(course)
```

Comment: how would i get the course back in a snapshot? and put it in an array so i can get the coursename for the label of a cell.